# Kolmogorv Smirnov Test in R

Tags: r, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, uniform-distribution

I want to proof the "Relative Age Effect" of a football team. I have a list of birth dates of the team members (about 20 numbers between 1 and 365, the day of the year).
I now want to use the KS-Test to test against a uniform distribution.

this is how I did it, but it looks very wrong to me:

> ks.test(dates,"punif")
>
> D = 1, p-value = 3.331e-16
> alternative hypothesis: two-sided

almost all players are born in the first half of the year, yet the p-value seems far too low in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ks.test(dates, "punif", 1, 365)
```

To understand why, try typing

```
?ks.test
```

and reading the last bit of the 'Details' section.

Comment: thanks. Isn't the reference distribution a continuous distribution between 1 and 365, in my case it's a discrete: it can only take values 1,..,365.

Comment: I don't think the discreteness would matter unless you had an awful lot more than 20 data points.